# PHP/OpenTBS/DocX nested arrays / subblock

Tags: php, docx, opentbs

Actually testing opentbs to generate a docx based on a template from my website. I'm facing a problem integrating images.
I succeeded to add images inside a loop, but my problem is integrating those in a nested loop.

I have an array of days Object and inside this an array of images path (with additional datas in each days)

My data schema is like this:

```
// Initialisation du Parser
$TBS = new clsTinyButStrong;
$TBS->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN);

// Chargement du fichier Modèle
$TBS->LoadTemplate(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/tbs/rendu-v2.docx', OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8);

$steps = array(
  stdClass {
    day: 'day 1',
    name: 'My 1st step',
    images: array(
      'pathToMyFirstImage',
      'pathToMySecondImage'
    )
  },
  stdClass {
    day: 'day 2 & 3',
    name: 'My 2st step',
    images: [
      'pathToMyThirdImage',
      'pathToMyFourthImage'
    ]
  }
);

$TBS->MergeBlock( 'steps2', $steps);
$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_DOWNLOAD);
```

In my word Template:

````
[steps2;block=begin]
  JOUR [steps2.day;sub1=images] : [steps2.name]
  [steps2.date]

  [steps2.description]

  [steps2_sub1; block=begin]
    [X] (picture with [steps2_sub1.val;ope=changepic;tagpos=inside] as text sustitution)
  [steps2_sub1; block=end]
[steps2; block=end]```
````

Actually, in the output file, my subblock is display as this and not interpreted.

I looked at this solution [OpenTBS - How to use a double loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164365/opentbs-how-to-use-a-double-loop) but end part is a little Strange and not working either with only `[steps2_sub1;block=end]`.

OpenTBS doc doesn't give full example of subblocks with block.

Does anyone see what I misunderstand?

EDIT : My subblock doesn't work and is displayed as "code" and not interpreted.

Thanks,

Mathieu

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Hello, lol, right, I wasn't clear, I can't make work my subblock, it still put in my docx my subblock as it is in code and not as it should be interpreted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that TBS is space sensitive : I had a space before semicolon of sub1 in my begin block (MS Word add it automaticaly in FR language).

Working code is next :

```
[steps2;block=begin;sub1=images]
[STEPS2.DAY] : [STEPS2.NAME]
[steps2.date]

[steps2.description;strconv=no]

[X] <- Image with "[steps2_sub1.val;ope=changepic;tagpos=inside;block=tbs:p]" as Text Replacement

[steps2;block=end]
```

Thanks all

By the way, how can I manage various way of displaying my pictures?
I'll have 0 to 4 pictures to display like that :

```
|    My Page     |
|                |
| Case 1 image   |
[   100% Width   ]
|                |
| Case 2 images  |
[  50%  ][  50%  ]
|                |
| Case 3 images  |
[  50%  ][  50%  ]
[      100%      ]
|                |
| Case 4 images  |
[  50%  ][  50%  ]
[  50%  ][  50%  ]
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Comment: I manage this by using 4 blocks with when condition (I know this is not recommanded but that's the only way to manage a "div" for multiple items) and transform my picture array into pictures with static names in the object (img1, img2, …). Depending on condition I put 2 columns or one.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 errors in your snippet.

1) TBS is case sensitive.

So the snippet:

```
[STEPS2.DAY;SUB1=IMAGES]
```

should be replaced with:

```
[steps2.day;sub1=images]
```

2) parameter 'sub1' is a block parameter, so it should be defined only in the field that has parameter 'block'. Otherwise it is ignored.

So the snippet:

```
[steps2;block=begin]
[steps2.day;sub1=images]
```

should be replaced with:

```
[steps2;block=begin;sub1=images]
[steps2.day]
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, for 1st error, it's not one, it's the font that is in caps.

Comment: On the second one, if I do this I have a block's definition error on steps2 : TinyButStrong Error in block's definition [steps2...]: at least one tag corresponding to begin  is not found. Check opening tags, closing tags and embedding levels. My word Template is like this : https://postimg.cc/image/7twrvecln/

Comment: I've tested the snipped I've submitted and it worked for me. Maybe some of your tags have been internally split and you have to cut and paste without formatting in order to have them clean. Or you can use the TBS plugin for Ms Word given in the package. I also suggest to avoid using `block=begin` with DOCX or other documents. It is less sensitive to define block with something like `block=tbs:p`.

Comment: Thanks for taking time for my problem. It appears that TBS is space sensitive : I had a space before semicolon of sub1 in my begin block (MS Word add it automaticaly in FR language).